# Why does my Junit-AssertionError-Test fail?

Tags: java, junit

I run the following test in my Eclipse (with arguments -ea):

```
public class ColorHelperTest
{
    @Rule
    public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();

    @Test
    public void testGetColorByString()
    {
        thrown.expect(AssertionError.class);
        assert 1 == 2;
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
java.lang.AssertionError
at de.*.*.*.mytests.ColorHelperTest.testGetColorByString(ColorHelperTest.java:28)
```

28 is the line `assert 1==2`

Why does this test fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot "expect" `AssertionError`, this is the specific type of error that JUnit uses to signal that the test is failing.

**Update**: Turns out it's a bug of JUnit 4.11, and it was resolved in 4.12:
https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/doc/ReleaseNotes4.12.md#pull-request-583-pull-request-720-fix-handling-of-assertionerror-and-assumptionviolatedexception-in-expectedexception-rule

Answer (score 1):

The `assert` keyword is a JRE level flag and has nothing to do with JUnit.  I think what you're really looking for is:

```
assertEquals(1, 2);
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was misleading you, but the assert was only an example. I don't care if 1 != 2 ;-)

Comment: I want to find out how to catch AssertionErrors thrown by other methods.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting... What version of Junit you use? Using 4.12 (in my pom.xml looks like:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

the exact same test works for me.

Comment: Did you set the `-ea` flag? Without it, the `assert` keyword is ignored.

Comment: I did. Also I wouldn't get an AssertionError if I didn't.

Comment: I find it very strange, that this works for you. That contradicts @Sergey ?!

Comment: I just checked with versions 4.11 and 4.12, and the behavior indeed differs. With 4.11 I receive AssertionError, with 4.12 the test passes.

Comment: Here's the reason, turns out it was a bug of versions prior to 4.12 https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/doc/ReleaseNotes4.12.md#pull-request-583-pull-request-720-fix-handling-of-assertionerror-and-assumptionviolatedexception-in-expectedexception-rule

Comment: Sure, -ea must be there, meaning the real issue is the version of Junit. So my answer is useful Nils? ^^

Comment: My bad Phani, I am sorry.